# How we get Profile url in linkedin auth api v2?

Tags: asp.net, oauth-2.0, linkedin-api

We are using previous version v1 of linkedin. We are getting firstname, last name, email, heading, profile url,profile image etc. Now linkedin created v2 and giving access liteprofile only. And we are getting firstname, lastname ,email, profile image only. not able to get profile url.
We are using this authentication in survey site I need profileurl as well in authentication that possible with basic profile.
In need profile URL in this API. I have already applied for developer program but rejected.I can get this url by paid services if any from linkedin please confirm?

**GET https://api.linkedin.com/v2/me**

[Linked In Login Integration response](https://i.stack.imgur.com/JctPJ.png)

Comment: Were you able to figure out a solution for this? I'm also looking for the profile URL in addition to the oauth flow + v2/me API call.

Answer (score 0):

If you're a programmer, you don't need to buy any paid services. You can use Google Custom Search JSON API to get LinkedIn Profile URL, even Job Title ;-)

`site:linkedin.com {query}`

[image: LinkedIn Profile URL and Headline without Partner]

Good luck!